# Visual studio need space on D:

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to install Visual studio 2019 but when I hit install, Visual studio installer prompt a message saying It needs 2go on D: drive. The problem is that D: is an encrypted disk and I can't change the letter because of portability issues.I have plenty of space on C: and B:
I took a screenshot it's in french but I hope it is easy enough to understand. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jmd6.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not obvious from the snapshot where or why `D:` comes into this picture. Is D: used for temp files, or the user profile directory, or ..? If B: and/or C: have enough free space, you could try to disconnect D: and rerun the installer so that it's not tempted to use it at all.

Comment: I don't know why it want to install on D: I never specified D: anywhere and unfortunately I can't disconnect it

Comment: If D: is the only volume on the disk, you can (temporarily) set it to Offline in Disk Management, otherwise you could (temporarily) unassign it the drive letter also in Disk Management.

Comment: I set offline the drive and it has worked thank you !